# Using formsets for my fileupload does not work when doing an update class based view only on create in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

I have used as many examples online as I could cobble together in an attempt to get my two simple models to have the ability to do an inline formset allowing me to add many files to a technial drawing.
This is not working, I can only add one file for the Create and the update only updates the Technical_Entry model, not a file...which in of itself acts funny.  The UI ona  create shows one spot to add a file, then save the entire record and its child record.  That works.
The update, the UI shows the file that was saved earlier..(great!) but then has two more 'choose file' slots (random?) and adding a file to those does nothing when the save is clicked.  It doesn't remove the file previously added in the create, but it also
does not save the new file added to the now three slots (one used, two free).   So update does not work for the files for some reason.

```
class Technical_Entry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ema = models.ForeignKey(EMA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    system = models.ForeignKey('System', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # are SYSTEMS RELATED TO SUBSYSTEMS OR JUST TWO GROUPS?  
    sub_system = models.ForeignKey(SubSystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    drawing_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    drawing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    engineer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_drawn = models.DateField()
    ab = models.BooleanField()



class Technical_Entry_Files(models.Model):
    tech_entry = models.ForeignKey(Technical_Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='techdb/files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tech_entry.drawing_number
```

To upload using a formset.  While the page 'displays' mostly correctly, it flat out does not create the record in the Technical_Entry_Files model.

Relevant forms.py:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    
    class Meta:
        model = Technical_Entry_Files
        fields = ('file',)

TechFileFormSet  = inlineformset_factory(Technical_Entry, Technical_Entry_Files, form=FileUploadForm, extra=1, max_num=15)



class Technical_EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Technical_EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = Technical_Entry
        fields = ('category', 'ema', 'system', 'sub_system', 'drawing_number', 'drawing_title', 'engineer', 'vendor', 'date_drawn', 'ab')


        widgets = {
            'date_drawn':DateInput(attrs={
            'class':'datepicker form-control',        
            'id' : 'datetimepicker2',
            'tabindex' : '1',
            'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm',          
            'autocomplete':'off',
            }, format='%m/%d/%Y'),

            'system' : Select(attrs={'tabindex':'2'}),
        }
```

Relevant views.py:

```
class TechEntryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    print ("we are here")
    model = Technical_Entry
    form_class = Technical_EntryForm
    template_name = 'techdb/tech_entry_form.html'
    print(template_name)
    success_url = '/techentry_add'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(TechEntryCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['file_upload'] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['file_upload'] = TechFileFormSet()
        return data


    def form_valid(self, form):
        context =self.get_context_data()
        file_upload = context['file_upload']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if file_upload.is_valid():
                file_upload.instance =self.object
                file_upload.save()
        return super(TechEntryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class TechEntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):                                                                                             

    model = Technical_Entry
    form_class = Technical_EntryForm
    template_name = 'techdb/tech_entry_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
                                                                                             
                                                                                         

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                
        context = super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(instance=self.object)    
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        file_upload = context["file_upload"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if file_upload.is_valid():
            file_upload.instance =self.object
            file_upload.save()
        return super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and the tech_entry_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% load static %}

{% block page-js %}

<script>
    $('.link-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add file',
        deleteText: 'remove',        
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<main role="main" class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>New Tech Entry</h1>
      </div>

    <h2> Details of Technical Entry </h2>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
       <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <h2> Files </h2>
                {{ file_upload.management_form }}
                {% for upload_form in file_upload.forms %}
                  <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ upload_form.file }}        
                  </div>
                 {% endfor %}

               
                <input type="submit" value="Save"/><a href="{% url 'tech_database:index' %}">back to the list</a>
            </form>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </main><!-- /.container -->


{% endblock %}
```

And what the UI looks like on edit...

[image]

Comment: when you create, were you able to upload multiple images?

Comment: nope that didn't work at all.  So was concentrating on doing a create and just getting a single upload to work, which does!  then figured step two was getting the ability to edit that upload on an update view to work, that is what is not working here.  THen down the road...step 3 is letting me upload many images and then ultimately delete/change the multiple images in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TechEntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):                                                                                             

    model = Technical_Entry
    form_class = Technical_EntryForm
    template_name = 'techdb/tech_entry_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
                                                                                             
    #log_entry_class = Technical_EntryForm(Technical_Entry) #removed
                                                                                         
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                
        context = super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #self.object = self.get_object() #removed

        if self.request.POST:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,instance=self.object)
        else:
            context["file_upload"] = TechFileFormSet(instance=self.object)

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        file_upload = context["file_upload"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if file_upload.is_valid():
            file_upload.instance =self.object
            file_upload.save()
        #return super().form_valid(form)
        return super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).form_valid(form) #replaced old one
```

**UPDATE**
**1.** in order to be able to add mulitple files when creating,

```
TechFileFormSet  = inlineformset_factory(Technical_Entry, Technical_Entry_Files, form=FileUploadForm, extra=4, max_num=4)

# note I changed to extra=4, if you always want to have only 4 files, then also change to max_num=4
```

**2.** When update, the reason why the update is not working even after modifying the views was because you were not passing  `hidden fields`. You were not passing the `id`s of the files, therefore, your formsets were not passing `.is_valid()`, hence, no update. Add for loop about hidden fields like below.

```
{{ file_upload.management_form }}
   {% for upload_form in file_upload.forms %}

      {% for hidden in upload_form.hidden_fields %}
            {{hidden}}
      {% endfor %}

             <div class="link-formset">
                    {{ upload_form.file }}        
                  </div>
                 {% endfor %}
```

#Note the `for loop` I add about `hidden fields`.

Comment: Did this verbatim (edited OP).  Still no dice.  Posted a screen shot of what the UI looks like on edit too...

Comment: thanks for the screenshot. So, 1) it looks like the instance works, because you nsee the created file. 2) what things are not working?

Comment: The create works! I can post a screen shot of that too.  Posted here is the Update view...it fills out the fields as it should from the database, if I change a field it does indeed respect that change and reflect in the database.  It knows that its trying to edit the file...there is the 'current' pointing to the file i uploaded when I did the create...but if I goto change the file, that is not actually changed in the db or no new file on disk.

Comment: Additionally...I wouldn't want to change so much as delete and add more (arbitrary number of them) So the edit on the file portion just isn't working and even if it did work and let me change... its still not the final incarnation I need.

Comment: just to be sure, you had changed the last line of updateview, right?

Comment: Yep updated to        return super(TechEntryUpdateView, self).form_valid(form) #replaced old one. I think sometimes web coding in general there is a lot one doesn't have to learn because it is 'automagic' then when you try to get outside the norm, you wish you knew the internals.  That is the case here.  I have been successful with 90% of my apps I have built.  This is just cooking my brain, and I know to let me add multiple files later I will need to work more on html side and with that jquery formset I am sure.... Figured trying to get this simple case working start to finish first.

Comment: I updated my aswer, please check, this time should work! both creating multiple files, and update the record.

Comment: a bit confused.Are you using select2 jquery library or django-autocomplete-light that supports select2.js?

Comment: BRUHHHH you are a straight G.  It works, it is not as elegant as I had envisioned in my mind with just no files and a plus buttton to add more etc etc but I am sure that is all some javascript love.  The rest works at it's core.  It shows 4 slots, and I put the max to 10.  So guessing again java script to let me add some more but now I know i have a solid base to work from ty so much!

Comment: Great to hear that it workd! At the end, I had to resort js library (i used filepond), because the default inlineformset is not so...user-friendly.

Comment: resorted to filepond just to get it to work ? or for all the pretty adding new files at a whim or deleting them?

Comment: inlineformset works! I later used filepond, because it allows drag-and-drop multiple files, resize them, preview them, etc...

Comment: I just found a post on using filepond with django (written by you :) ) so I am going to comb over that and make the UI look much nicer I hope.

Comment: LOL, the only thing that I was not happy about it long time ago (maybe it is fixed), is that if you upload 4 files, I wished I could click one of them and set it as a main image (the cover image). I was not able to do it and I asked a question and was hoping the developer would answer but he did not (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793579/add-an-icon-div-to-the-preview-images-when-onactivatefile-is-fired-filepond/61306138#61306138). In this post, I had a workaround, but was not ideal.

Comment: Well this seems like some good info to start on, I think if I can integrate it well with django as I have it setup now that would be so ideal to let an arbritary number of images and files be uploaded and then also removed (realized I don't have an option to delete an uploaded file in my update, I can change but no remove..I gotta add that)